# How can I mock part of a Spring Boot service for ALL of my Spock Integration tests?

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, mocking, spock

I am using Spock to create integration tests for my Spring Boot Application, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to mock part of a Service for **all** my test cases.

My app writes to an Azure Cosmos database running in Gremlin Graph mode, and since I don't know of any in-memory databases to adequately simulate it, I would like to make sure any service that writes to my development database only interacts with entities labeled with the current test's random UUID. So any service that reads/writes to the database needs to make sure to include the current test ID in any query.

What's the best way to mock a couple reused methods in an abstract base class via Spock?

GraphService.groovy <== The abstract class with some methods I wish to mock.

```
abstract class GraphService {
    @Autowired 
    protected GraphTraversalSource g

    protected GraphTraversal buildBaseQuery() {
        return g.V()
    } 

    protected GraphTraversal buildBaseCreationQuery(String label) {
        return g.addV(label)
    }
}
```

Several database searching/modifying services inherit the above class. For all of my tests, instead of `g.V()` I want `g.V().has("testID", testId)` and instead of `g.addV(label)` I want `g.addV(label).property("testID", testId)`. How can I accomplish this across all my integration tests? I tried creating a base-specification class that specified this behavior, but it didn't work.

TestConfig.groovy

```
@Configuration
class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    GraphPersistenceService persistenceService(
            GraphTraversalSource g) {
        DetachedMockFactory mockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()
        GraphPersistenceService persistenceService = mockFactory.Stub( //Mock doesn't work either
            [constructorArgs: [g]], GraphPersistenceService)
        return graphPersistenceService
    }
}
```

BaseIntegrationTest.groovy

```
class BaseIntegrationTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    TestUtil testUtil

    @Autowired
    GraphTraversalSource g

    @Autowired
    GraphPersistenceService persistenceService

    def setup() {
        persistenceService.buildBaseQuery >> g.V().has("testID", testUtil.id)
        persistenceService.buildBaseCreationQuery(_ as String) >> { label ->
            g.addV(label).property("testID", testUtil.id)
        }
    }

    def cleanup() {
        testUtil.removeAllEntitiesWithCurrentTestId()
    }
}
```

And then in an actual test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyGraphApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [GraphDbConfig.class, TestConfig.class])
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = 'classpath:application-local.properties')
class UserOfPersistenceServiceSpec extends BaseIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    UserOfGraphPersistenceService userOfPersistenceService

    def "Can create a bunch of vertices"() {
        expect:
        userOfPersistenceService.createABunchOfVertices() == 5
    }
}
```

PS. I'm using Spring 1.5.10.RELEASE and groovy 2.4.15...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If upgrading to Spock 1.2 is an option for you, I suggest ditching the TestConfig class and using the `@SpringBean` annotation.

This is an example of how I have it set up in my tests:

```
@ActiveProfiles(["integrationtest"])
@DirtiesContext
abstract class IntegrationTest extends Specification {

    @SpringBean
    EurekaClient eurekaClient = Mock() {
        getNextServerFromEureka(*_) >> Mock(InstanceInfo) {
            getHomePageUrl() >> "test.test"
        }
    }

//    ... other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks promising, but I think I need to use Spy somehow, if I'm reading some of these articles correctly. I want the rest of my Service to function normally, I just want to override a couple specific methods. Mock would require me to redefine every method I want a response from, right?

Comment: @SnoopDougg yes, in that case you want a Spy. The rest should be the same though